# Proving that a query is a blocking issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When running this query, so far there are 4 different results that can occur, but with the most frequency the main result is that it runs for over 10 minutes before I kill it, but around 1% of the time it will return either 2 records or 3 records or no records:

```
select *
from [master] as [p]( nolock )
     inner join eddd(nolock) as [e]
     on [p].[guid] = [e].pggg
     inner join stppp as [s]( nolock )
     on [e].[guid] = [s].evggg
     inner join [edddex] as [x]( nolock )
     on [e].[guid] = [x].[guid]
where [p].[guid] = '370ECB0F-6222-4D02-86DD-336BAAA49B81'
  and ( CAST([s].rddd as date) = '20150821'
     or CAST([s].rddd as date) = '20150821' )
  and [s].[st111num] = 4
  and [e].[ev111type] = 6
  and [x].[l11105] = 6;
```

My friend argues that because removing this filter:

```
  and ( CAST([s].rddd as date) = '20150821'
     or CAST([s].rddd as date) = '20150821' )
```

causes the query to respond immediately, that this proves this is not a blocking/locking issue.

**When having only SELECT access against a specific database and not having the ability to audit or view system tables, how does one find out whether a specific query is returning different results due to locking?**

Comment: This is a query/performance issue.  Because a query/performance issue can *cause* a blocking/locking issue you cannot completely separate these two things.  I would suggest that you first fix the performance problem in this query as that is likely to fix any blocking problems there might be.

Comment: Remove the `NOLOCK` hints and see if your query starts returning consistent results. What isolation is your database set for?

Comment: @RBarryYoung how can you tell it's a performance problem?

Comment: @alroc thank you, how do i get the isolation for the db vs transaction level?

Comment: @Of9s30 Because the part that you removed is the kind of conditional clause that cannot leverage indexes effectively and when you remove it, the problem goes away.  This is a very typical query performance problem.  Blocking issues are affected by other users/queries.  Failure to use indexes leads to all kinds of problems, notably table scans which cause poor performance and can also frequently cause blocking issues.

Comment: @RBarryYoung actually the execution plan shows that it does use the index on that column

Comment: Can we see the actual execution plan? Seems strange that the problem would only occur with that clause in if it's actually using an index there. Also, how many rows are in these tables? (And have you tried the obvious stuff, like not casting to a date, or adding a computed column on s.rddd as a date and indexing it? e.g. what happens if you use `[s].rddd >= '20150821' AND [s].rddd < '20150822'`, which is presumably functionally equivalent, assuming rddd is a datetime...)

Comment: Unlikely that it uses any index *effectively* for that condition though.  Posting the query plan would be a big help here also, as that is what we use to figure this out for more complicated and/or ambiguous cases.

Comment: Do you not have DBA's that you can enlist to check for blocking while the query is running?

Comment: heres the execution plan http://i.imgur.com/vCHLXH3.png

Comment: Are the indexes being used 'ordered' or for a full scan ?  how much data is  actually being scanned ?  And the 20% KeyLookup means that the indexes aren't really tuned for this.

Comment: @Amir for a full scan, how much data? 200 million records

Comment: @Amir how would you further tune the indexes?

Comment: you need a dba to look at the tables and tune the query.

Answer (score 0):

The    CAST([s].rddd      is the performance problem.   When you put a function (   Like CAST(), MAX(), etc   )   around a criteria field, you disable the use of the index that would otherwise aid in the execution of your query, and this causes a full table scan.   Modify your query so that you can avoid use of such functions, AND, be sure your filters/matches involve the LEADING index fields.  Not employing the leading index fields ALSO causes the indexe(s) to not be used.

For more insight, run an EXPLAIN PLAN ( Show Plan ...whichever you system utilizes ) and it will tell you what indexes are used, and much more.

Also,....    SELECT * is a performance killer, as it has to return ALL FIELDS, so even if the indexes can assist with the filtering, every block containing any of the needed records must be fully read.  SELECT * is very rarely needed, so visit that as well and trim it down to only the needed fields.

Comment: thank you very much for this insightful answer, what do you mean by this: LEADING index fields. Not employing the leading index fields ALSO causes the indexe(s) to not be used.

Comment: Leading fields means :  Consider a table with say 20 columns, 3 of which make up the Primary Key index.  Table name is SALES and COLS includes CUSTID, BOOK_DATE, SHIP_DATE, ITEM_NUM, QTY, SALES_AGENT, DISCOUNT_PCT, etc.    The PK would likely need BOOK_DATE, CUST_ID, and lets add SALES_AGENT,  and in THAT seqencial order.    If I write a query on this and don't specify the BOOK_DATE ( the leading field ) but do specify the CUST_ID, that index wont be used.  BOOK_DATE is the leading field in the index.  Skipping it means that index cant be used.  An index starting with CUST_ID would be needed.

Comment: Naturally, using all of the index fields is better using just one or a few, but the index benefit ends with the very first index field that IS NOT used in a WHERE filter or JOIN condition.  Thus, awareness and understanding of all indexes on all involved tables is important for performance.

Comment: Sub note :   remember that conditions specified in the WHERE clause are enforce as if they were applied within an INNER join..i.e:  no match causes the row to be eliminated from results.  Conditions in a LEFT OUTER join tolerate failed matches.   So, take care in placement of condition tests  JOIN conditions and WHERE condition are not always treated equally.

Comment: Sub note 2 :  The query must determine :  "which rows are to be returned", before it can carry out the row fetches.  It attempts to answer that using indexes.  When it can't, it resorts to full table scans.   THAT is where the heavy locking comes from.  Those will be BLOCK level locks, vs ROW level locks, greatly increasing the impact upon your own query which must wait for other Insert/Update/Delete queries to release each block, and  increasing the impact upon other queries that are awaiting exclusive control so that they may safely Insert/Update/Delete within any given block.